# Vue / Nuxt webpack resolve error on require image file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js, nuxt-content

I'm getting a webpack error when trying to require an image file I know exists in my v-img component [here](https://github.com/brianssparetime/blog/blob/vimgtn/components/VImg.vue#L59):

```
    imgSrcFancy (imgsize) {
      try {
        // if in production, unless no imgsize is specified, use .imgs instead of fullsize
        // if (imgsize === '' || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        if (imgsize === '') { // temporarily force always use .imgs for testing only
          console.log('fallback on full-rez load')
          return require(`~/content${this.dirp}/${this.src}`)
        } else { // production and imgsize not empty
          const path = require('path')
          const ext = path.extname(this.src)
          const name = path.basename(this.src, ext)
          const loadstring = `~/content${this.dirp}/.imgs/${name}_${imgsize}${ext}`
          console.log('fancy load from ' + loadstring)
          return require(`~/content${this.dirp}/.imgs/${name}_${imgsize}${ext}`)
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('error with finding image for:  ' + this.src)
        console.log(error)
        return null
      }
```

**Background**:

I have a [blog](https://github.com/brianssparetime/blog) that uses nuxt-content.

The project is organized so that images are grouped along with post .md files in a folder for each post inside /content/posts.  My starting [v-img component](https://github.com/brianssparetime/blog/blob/master/components/VImg.vue) works fine, requiring these images no problem.  (**note** this last link is to the master branch that is deployed, while the earlier is to a feature branch)

My [deployed site](https://www.brianssparetime.com/) is very slow to load, so I wrote a [python program](https://github.com/brianssparetime/blog/blob/vimgtn/gen_tn.py) to generate smaller versions of the images, all stored in a .imgs folder within each slug folder as follows:

```
 - content/
   - posts/
     - post-slug-one/
       - index.md
       - my_image1.jpg
       ...
       - .imgs/
         - my_image1_large.jpg
         - my_image1_tn.jpg
         ...
```

The python program is invoked as part of my netlify build command, e.g. `python3 ./gen_tn.py && nuxt build && nuxt generate`.  This works fine.

To avoid clogging up disk space locally, I'm using NODE_ENV to just use full sizes when in development; this works fine too, but I've temporarily disabled this to test.

I generated thumbnails locally for testing, but the problem comes when I hit the line:

```
return require(`~/content${this.dirp}/.imgs/${name}_${imgsize}${ext}`)
```

I get an exception:

```
Error: Cannot find module './content/posts/sept-2021-photos-things/.imgs/pos_DSC01274_large.jpg'
    at webpackContextResolve (content.*$:752)
    at webpackContext (content.*$:747)
    at VueComponent.imgSrcFancy (VImg.vue:59)
    at Proxy.render (VImg.vue?ad21:7)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (vue.runtime.esm.js:3548)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js:4055)
    at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js:4479)
    at Watcher.run (vue.runtime.esm.js:4554)
    at flushSchedulerQueue (vue.runtime.esm.js:4310)
    at Array.<anonymous> (vue.runtime.esm.js:1980)
```

But this file exists:

```
MBPro:bst-blog$ ls content/posts/sept-2021-photos-things/.imgs/pos_DSC01274_large.jpg
content/posts/sept-2021-photos-things/.imgs/pos_DSC01274_large.jpg
```

I've tried even hard-coding the image size, but that doesn't work either:

```
return require(\`~/content${this.dirp}/.imgs/${name}_large${ext}`)
```

What am I doing wrong?  How do I fix this?  Any guidance appreciated!

Comment: I've also tried ```return require(`~/content${this.dirp}/.imgs/${this.src.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, '')}_large.png'`)``` to keep things as close to the working example and provide webpack as much literal text as possible.  But still not working.  Do I need to tell webpack somewhere else about the .img directories?

Comment: ```return require(`~/content${this.dirp}/.imgs/${this.src.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, '')}_large.png`)``` rather (stray ' in the previous).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.

Turns out the problem was with the name I was using for the thumbnails - webpack did not like .imgs.  Changing it to imgs (or gen_tn_imgs to make adding a specific rule to .gitignore easy, in my case).

My final block looks like this:

```
 methods: {
    imgSrcFancy (imgsize) {
      try {
        // if in production, unless no imgsize is specified, use .imgs instead of fullsize
        if (imgsize === '' || imgsize === 'orig' || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        // if (imgsize === '') { // temporarily force always use .imgs for testing only
          console.log('fallback on full-rez load')
          return require(`~/content${this.dirp}/${this.src}`)
        } else { // production and imgsize not empty
          const path = require('path')
          const ext = path.extname(this.src)
          const name = path.basename(this.src, ext)
          const loadstring = `~/content${this.dirp}/gen_tn_imgs/${name}_${imgsize}.png`
          console.log('fancy load from ' + loadstring)
          return require(`~/content${this.dirp}/gen_tn_imgs/${name}_${imgsize}.png`) // working
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('error with finding image for:  ' + this.src)
        console.log(error)
        return null
      }
    }
  }
```

and it's called like so:

```html
    <a :href="imgSrcFancy('orig')">
      <img :src="imgSrcFancy('large')" :alt="alt">
    </a>
```